# extracting html element with cherrio

Tags: html, meteor, cheerio

This Meteor server code uses cheerio and tries to extract the text 'John', I tried the few different ways below for no avail.
`console.log(e.next.children.eq(1).text());
console.log(e.next.children.last().text());
console.log(e.next.contents().last().text());`

How can it be done with cheerio? Thanks

```
ResObj.$("table").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 8;
}).each(function(i, e) {
  if (e.nodeValue.trim() == 'CONTACTS') {
    console.log(e.next.contents('td').eq(1).text()); //<----------
    console.log(e.nextSibling.nodeType);  // returns 3
  }
});


<!-- CONTACTS -->
<tr>
  <td class="label" valign="top" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">
    Names of people:&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </td>
  <td class="displayValue" valign="top">

    John

  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheerio is just like jQuery (for the most part), so why are you building this complex structure when all it look like you need is:

```
$('table .displayValue').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Let's break down the code you have:

```
// Get all tables contents, then filter the data
ResObj.$("table").contents().filter(function() {
  // Only return Comments? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType ... also you should be using ===
  return this.nodeType == 8;
// Loop through all of the filtered elements
}).each(function(i, e) {
  // Check the string of the comment for the text you want --- This is bad style
  if (e.nodeValue.trim() == 'CONTACTS') {
    console.log(e.next.contents('td').eq(1).text()); //<----------
    console.log(e.nextSibling.nodeType);  // returns 3
  }
});
```

So are their reasons why you are going through all these loops, just to get a selector that has a class which is easily accessible?